# 2003 Mazda 6 power windows not worKing

Tags: power-windows

I plugged the driver side window control switch in from a Mazda 3 it blew the fuse on pass side fuse box when I replaced the fuse and plugged original switches back in it blew the fuse again replaced first and still nothing but window controls are still working HELP ME PLEASE THE MISSUS IS KILLING ME OVER IT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fault find blown cigarette lighter fuse](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43060/fault-find-blown-cigarette-lighter-fuse)

Answer (score 1):

You have a short somewhere.

The purpose of a fuse is to be the weak link in a circuit. If more current is running through a circuit than it was built to handle, a fuse will self destruct and break the circuit, preventing overheating and possible fire. The most likely causes of a circuit having too much current are too many devices drawing too much power on a wire, or a wire that is connected directly from power to ground with no components providing resistance.

I would guess that one of the circuits on that fuse is grounded where it shouldn't be. Too much current is flowing through the fuse, and it's self destructing. You'll need to check the wiring and see if it has power or ground somewhere it shouldn't.